# How to delete all the music from the iPad I'm planning to sell?

Tags: ipad, music.app

I am selling my iPad as I have a new one. How do I erase all my music so there is nothing in the music app? I've deleted the music but the albums are still there.

Answer (score 1):

You should do more than just remove the music.

`Settings` -> `General` -> `Reset` -> `Erase All content and settings`.

Effectively this sets the iPad back to the out of box state, so that the new owner can fully configure.  You may be prompted for an iCloud password if you have installed the Find My Iphone app.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to just delete the musics, you can go to:
Setting -> usage -> music